# What does the error RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant mean

Tags: django

To be specific, I have a standalone script in my django app folder, which is accessing the models,as per the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) you have to do the following configuration:

```
import os
import django

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = settings_file
django.setup()
```

But when i run the server i get the error

```
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

In the same directory as i have the models.py file I have a utils.py file which is my standalone script and my import statement goes as follows:

```
import os
import django

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sdn.settings'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    django.setup()

import requests
from .models import Location, BandwidthLogs, InterfaceLogs, Summary
```

I get the error that models cannot be imported.

Comment: It means Django initialisation has been invoked twice. This can happen in mod_wsgi if some error occurred when loading your settings module. The next time mod_wsgi tries to load your WSGI script in the same process, you get that error. If you are using mod_wsgi, you must go back and find the original first error message as it will tell you want the real problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to execute `django.setup()` more than once by simply importing it. Wrap the call inside a `__main__` block, i.e.:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    django.setup()
```

That being said, I would write a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) instead of a standalone script as it sets up the environment for you.

Comment: Yes i am calling django.setup() more than once, first in Celery.py file and second in the standalone script

Comment: You shouldn't. The doc page you linked to in your question mentions that too: `django.setup() may only be called once.`

Comment: when I wrap it up in the __main__ block, than I am not able to import the models.

Comment: Try putting your import statements into the `__main__` block as well.

Comment: after putting my import statements in the __main__block, i am getting the following error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'megaport_sdn.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Comment: You are missing a lot of information in your question. You wrote that it is a standalone script but now it looks like it is being loaded by WSGI. Please improve your question statement and include as much information as you can.

Comment: Thanks Selcuk, your idea for creating a separate Management command really helped me out.